# Меняется эффект dropshadow при прокрутке combobox в JavaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx, combobox

Пишу простенькое приложение на JavaFx, сам новичок.

[image: Правильная работа hover]  [image: Неправильная работа hover]

Все графические элементы добавляю в Scene Builder, сам пишу CSS стили для объектов в CSS файлах. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что после прокрутки колесиком мышки в Combobox меняется эффект hover для cell в combobox.

Очень сильно сомневаюсь, что это баг javaFx, а не моя ошибка.

Что я пытался сделать:

1. Думал, что проблема в конфликтах CSS стилей, но удалив все прошлые, эффект разных dropshadow остался.
2. Думал может дело в моем железе (ну там недостаток производительности) - при смене на более мощное железо эффект остался (разный drowshadow).
3. Менял параметры dropshadow - баг все равно оставался.

Вот мой CSS код:

```css
.combo-box .list-view .list-cell:hover {
    -fx-translate-y: -2px;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( gaussian , rgba(0,0,0,0.8) , 15, 0 , 0 , 8 );
}

.combo-box .increment-arrow, .combo-box .decrement-arrow {
    -fx-background-color: #9e5ce4; /* Цвет стрелочек у ползунка ползунка */
    -fx-border-width: 1px;
}

.combo-box .thumb {
    -fx-background-color: #9e5ce4;
}

.combo-box .track {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-opacity: 0;
}

.combo-box {
    -fx-background-color: #9e5ce4;
    -fx-border-color: #ccc;
    -fx-border-radius: 3px;
    -fx-padding: 5px;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.combo-box .arrow-button {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.combo-box .arrow-button .arrow {
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-shape: "M 0 0 L 4 5 L 8 0 Z";
    -fx-translate-x: -2px;
    -fx-translate-y: 1px;
    -fx-transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.combo-box .list-view {
    -fx-background-color: #9e5ce4;
    -fx-border-color: #ccc;
    -fx-border-radius: 3px;
}

.combo-box .list-cell {
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-font-family: "Comic Sans MS";
    -fx-font-size: 14;
}

.combo-box .list-view .list-cell {
    -fx-padding: 5px;
    -fx-background-color: #9e5ce4;
}
```

Comment: кажется что тень неправильная именно в варианте без прокрутки, в стилях прописана широкая тень

Comment: @Gleb Кстати говоря, Вы правы, тут у меня широкая достаточно. Но все равно тогда почему такая проблема возможна? Не уж проблема в javaFx, ну очень сомневаюсь....